# How to Read destination in manifest.yml in Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a function which returns a hard coded URL to a destination. I want to define the destination URL in my `manifest.yml` file and read the URL from there.

Here is my `manifest.yml`:

```
applications:
  - name: rule_runtime 
    buildpack: java_buildpack
    path: target/com.sap.brms.web.app.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
    env:
      TARGET_RUNTIME: tomcat
      destinations: [  {"name":"bpmrulesrepository", "url":"https://example.com"}]
```

From this file, I want to get the value `https://example.com` when I start the application. I have been trying `System.getenv("bpmrulesrepository")`, but it is returning `null`.

Comment: Can not just add the line `bpmrulesrepository: https://example.com` instead of the `destinations` line? CF won't know how to split out that json into a name/value pair in the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `manifest.yml` file tells the cf cli how to deploy your application.  You can put configuration in here, but *only* because your `manifest.yml` file can be used to define environment variables.  In other words, your `manifest.yml` file can be used to set specific environment variables from which your application can later read configuration values.  Your application cannot directly read `manifest.yml`.

For example, if this is your `manifest.yml` file:

```
applications:
  - name: rule_runtime 
    buildpack: java_buildpack
    path: target/com.sap.brms.web.app.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
    env:
      TARGET_RUNTIME: tomcat
      destinations: [  {"name":"bpmrulesrepository", "url":"https://example.com"}]
```

Then you're telling the cf cli to define two environment variables:

1. `TARGET_RUNTIME` which is going to have the value `tomcat`
2. `destinations` which is going to have the value `[  {"name":"bpmrulesrepository", "url":"https://example.com"}]`

Thus if you want to get the `url` key, you'd need to first get the contents of the `destinations` env variable, parse it (looks like JSON) and then read the value of `url`.

As Scott mentioned in his comment above, you can save yourself some work by defining your environment variables so that they are easier to read by your application. For example, if you set `destinations_bpmrulesrepository_url` to `https://example.com`, then all you'd need to do is to read one env variable and you'd have your URL.

For what it's worth, you might also want to just put your configuration inside of `application.properties` or `application.yml`.  You have a Spring Boot app, so this is typically where your configuration would go.  Plus, because it's Spring Boot, you can easily override configuration settings from these files via environment variables, if necessary.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to reference the yaml file.
You should add this configuration class in your spring boot app.

```
 package xyx.partas.provider.lezzgoshop.config;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by afernandez on 16/09/2016.
 */
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class AppConfig {


    private static String YML_FILE = "manifest.yml";
    //Change the path
    public static final String DEFAULT_ETC_DIR = "/etc/partas-config";
    /**
     * The default etc directory can be overridden by setting the CORE_API_ETC environment variable.
     */
    public static final String CUSTOM_ETC_DIR_VAR = "CORE_API_ETC";

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {

        final String envEtcDir = System.getenv(CUSTOM_ETC_DIR_VAR);
        final String configDir = (envEtcDir == null) ? DEFAULT_ETC_DIR : envEtcDir;

        final String configFile = configDir + File.separatorChar + YML_FILE;
        log.info("Looking up configuration file: {}", configFile);
        File ymlFile = new File(configFile);
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        if (ymlFile.exists()) {
            log.info("Loading Configuration File: {}", ymlFile.getAbsoluteFile());

            yaml.setResources(new FileSystemResource(configFile));
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
        } else {
            log.info("Using project default Configuration File");
            //yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application-default.yml"));
           // propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
        }

        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }


}
```

From there, you could inject the Environment Bean.

```
 @Autowired
 public Environment environment;
```

From the injected bean, you could reference the defined property like this.
environment.getProperty("thePropertyKey");

Comment: The manifest.yml file is used by the 'cf' CLI when the app is pushed to Cloud Foundry. The file is not deployed with the app, so the app can't read its contents at runtime. So this solution isn't going to work.